# How to download file from website where the hyperlink shows as 'Javascript'

Tags: python

Things tried:

Inspect the page, but the specific hyperlink does not show any file path.

Tried with selenium to get the web element , but that does not have a submit/click option.

The page under discussion is 'https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/new-52-week-high-low-equity-market'

and the element is > `"<a href="javascript:;" onclick="downloadCSV('high')" class=""><img src="/assets/images/icon-xls.svg" alt="csv" title="csv" class=""> Download (.csv)</a>"`

Comment: Depends on what the `downloadCSV` function does. If it just appends the parameter to a URL, you can construct the URL and download that.

Comment: If you click on the button, it'll redirect to "https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-52Week?index=high&type=dataLtpGreater20&csv=true". You can try downloading from this URL.

Comment: i tried to search in the inspect element for 'downloadCSV' function but unable to find the same.

Comment: https://www.nseindia.com/api/live-analysis-52Week?index=high&type=dataLtpGreater20&csv=true says resource not available.